# Error: Invalid name in Prisma of node.js project

Tags: node.js, npm, prisma

I used Prisma in a node.js project when I ran the below command

```bash
npx prisma migrate dev
```

I faced with this error

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Error: Invalid name: "project name"
```

I don't know what the problem is that printed `Error: Invalid name` when I want to migrate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [npm Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file)

> The "name" field contains your package's name, and must be lowercase and one word, and may contain hyphens and underscores.

So I changed package.json's name in my project with

```
"name": "project-name"
```